# Calculus With Probability Distributions

Tags: probability-theory, derivatives, probability-distributions, random-variables, chain-rule

The Probability Theory course I'm following starts to take derivatives of cumulative distribution functions to find derived distributions without much explanation.  I want to understand this part in a bit more detail.  I can see eight possible forms of such a derivative...

$\frac{d}{dx}F_X (g(x))$
$\frac{d}{dx}F_X (g(y))$
$\frac{d}{dx}F_Y (g(x))$
$\frac{d}{dx}F_Y (g(y))$
$\frac{d}{dy}F_X (g(x))$
$\frac{d}{dy}F_X (g(y))$
$\frac{d}{dy}F_Y (g(x))$
$\frac{d}{dy}F_Y (g(y))$

My guesses for the first four formulas would be...

$\frac{d}{dx}F_X (g(x)) = f_X(g(x)) * \frac{dg}{dx}$
$\frac{d}{dx}F_X (g(y)) = f_X(g(y)) * \frac{dg}{dy} * \frac{dy}{dx}$
$\frac{d}{dx}F_Y (g(x)) = f_Y(g(x)) * \frac{dg}{dx}$
$\frac{d}{dx}F_Y (g(y)) = f_Y(g(y)) * \frac{dg}{dy} * \frac{dy}{dx}$

From here, I make the assumption that which random variable is derived and which random variable is "primary" is invisible to the differentiation procedure.  Thus, I proceed as though solving a CDF expression such as $\frac{d}{dx}F_X (g(y))$ is unchanged by whether $Y$ is derived from $X$, or $X$ is derived from $Y$.  If true, then we can specify one (we'll say that $Y$ is derived from $X$), and the remaining four formulas would be...

$\frac{d}{dy}F_X (g(x)) = f_X(g(x)) * \frac{dg}{dx} * \frac{dx}{dy}$
$\frac{d}{dy}F_X (g(y)) = f_X(g(y)) * \frac{dg}{dy}$
$\frac{d}{dy}F_Y (g(x)) = f_X(g(x)) * \frac{dg}{dx} * \frac{dx}{dy}$
$\frac{d}{dy}F_Y (g(y)) = f_Y(g(y)) * \frac{dg}{dy}$

However, I'm not sure if the chain rule is allowed to be applied "uphill" like this.

Are these eight formulas correct?  If not, what are the correct formulas for the derivatives of CDFs?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to understand from this question. When you say "$Y$ is derived from $X$," it sounds like you are considering a random variable $Y$ which is a *function of* $X$, and that you are interested in finding the probability density of $Y$. But there seems to be some confusion in the formulas you've written. For instance, the chain rule says that the first should actually read $$\frac{d}{dx} F_X(g(x)) = f_X(g(x)) \, g'(x),$$ since $F_X$ has derivative $f_X$.

Comment: @nahp Yeah, that sounds like the description of derived distributions I had in mind, and you're right that I was mixing up examples.  So do $\frac{d}{dx}F_X (g(x))$ and $\frac{d}{dx}F_Y (g(x))$ both have the same derivative (the derivative you suggested)?

Comment: The derivative (with respect to $x$) of $F_X(g(x))$ is the one in my first comment, but the other derivative is $$\frac{d}{dx} F_{\color{red} Y}(g(x)) = f_{\color{red} Y}(g(x)) \, g'(x).$$  When you look at the functions $F_X( \cdot )$ and $F_Y( \cdot )$, you should *think of the dot* as the variable. The capital letters $X$ and $Y$ are not actually variables of this function; they are just there to record the fact that $F_X$ is a function *based on* the distribution of the random variable $X$, and likewise with $F_Y$.

Comment: @nahp Gotcha, I edited the formulas, I think all eight should be good now?

Comment: Sure, if $y$ is considered a function of $x$ and $x$ a function of $y$. But this would just be to confirm the chain rule, which we already know. The formulas are all easy to derive if you know what each term means, so it's less important to understand what the formulas are and more important to understand how they're used.

Comment: For example, suppose you have a random variable $X$ whose p.d.f. is given by $$f_X(x) = \begin{cases} e^{-x}, & x \geq 0 \\ 0, & x < 0 . \end{cases}$$ If you want to know the p.d.f. of $Y = X^3$, you first look at the c.d.f. of $Y$: $$F_Y(y) = P(Y \leq y) = P(X \leq y^{1/3}) = F_X(y^{1/3}) .$$ You then differentiate with respect to $y$ to obtain the p.d.f.: $$f_Y(y) = \frac{d}{dy} F_Y(y) = f_X(y^{1/3}) \cdot \frac 1 3 y^{-2/3} .$$ We can then plug in the formula for $f_X$ to get our answer. Here we understand that $y$ is a variable which is *not a function of $x$*.